# Domain user unable to login to laptop for first time

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, domain, login-screen

I recently just setup a new Hp laptop for a user. when the user tries to login (domain account) he is getting welcome with his name for about 30 minutes then the machine will login with a temp account. he can login to his desktop just fine without issue. but this is the first time logging into this laptop and the machine will not let him login. i have changed several profile list entries for the temp profile to get it to login and i have just completed a re-image of the device and still not letting him login.

Edit: If i log into the machine no issues. the laptop is also joined to the domain.

any ideas and help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you log into the laptop yourself, do you experience the same problem?  Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question so it contains enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Is the machine also a domain member?